# How to build a legal URL for HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient

It seems my code below not working and I am not sure how to build a url string contain apostrophe, bracket and other for HttpClient

```
   string myUrl ="Http://XXXXX.net/Cust('10008')/AcctDetail

    string strUrl = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(myUrl);
    var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();         
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "swerefeqeaQw=");

    var response = await client.GetAsync(strUrl);            

    string status = response.StatusCode.ToString();


    Problem: at var response = await client.GetAsync(strUrl);  

System.InvalidOperationException: The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set
```

How to build such a url string for HttpClient?  I am using HttpClien to consume OData webservice which I find the URL requirement is diff. This Httpclient is used in Xamarin (Microsoft cross platform for Mobile)

Thanks

Comment: *not working*? In what way does it not work? You should know how to write better questions by now.

Comment: What's you front end built around too? MVC? MVC Core? WCF? Just plain WinForms?

Comment: That code looks like it won't even compile. The URL string is missing a closing quote and three of the lines are missing semicolons...

Comment: The above code does compile,  Please show working code and the exception.

Comment: @all, I have updated my code and the error Message.

Comment: @Austin  I am using Xamarin.forms

Answer (score -2):

If the server is standard REST, then perhaps the URL should be

```
string myUrl = "http://XXXXX.net/Cust/10008/AcctDetail";
```

Comment: How can you possibly guess this is the answer when we don't even know what the problem is? Also, please use proper code formatting, triple backticks are not the correct way to format on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DavidG It is just a guess to help the OP,  sorry about back ticks, been writing markdown documentation all day,

Comment: A guess is probably better served as a comment then.

Comment: Note the use of `perhaps`.  Let's try to help the OP and not bicker amonst ourselves,

Comment: Haha it's the word "perhaps" that makes this a comment and not an answer :)

Comment: @all really appreciate to help me. I have updated my code.